# EventListener for form is not working after unsubscribe button

Tags: javascript, forms, dom, event-listener

I have a little problem.Usign vanilla js i create a form for an email input that after a validation function is sent to localStorage and the state of the button is changed; i did an event listener for unsubscribing the email and it removes the email from localStorage but i can not subscribe again just after the unsubscribe,i can only after refreshing the page.
Some screenshots for more details:
I enter a valid email:
[image]

Click subscribe: [image]

Click unsubscribe without refreshing the page:
[image]

And in this state,i can not subscribe again with another email,it works only after refreshing but i need to do this without refresh.How can do i?
The section where this form is created is dinamically created.
Code:
Subscribe functions:

```
import { validateEmail } from './email-validator.js'

export const subscribe = () => {
  const subscribeBtn = document.getElementById('subscribeButton')
  subscribeBtn.setAttribute('value', 'Unsubscribe')
  document.getElementById('emailForm').style.display = 'none'
  localStorage.setItem('isSubscribed', 'true')
}

export const unsubscribe = () => {
  const subscribeBtn = document.getElementById('subscribeButton')
  subscribeBtn.setAttribute('value', 'Subscribe')
  document.getElementById('emailForm').style.display = 'block'
  localStorage.setItem('isSubscribed', 'false')
}

export const subscribeEmail = (email) => {
  const isValidEmail = validateEmail(email)
  if (isValidEmail === true) {
    subscribe()
    document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      unsubscribe()
      localStorage.removeItem('Email')
    })
  } else if (isValidEmail === false) {
    unsubscribe()
  }
}
```

Validation function:

```
    const VALID_EMAIL_ENDINGS = ['gmail.com', 'outlook.com', 'yandex.ru']

export const validateEmail = (email) => VALID_EMAIL_ENDINGS.some(v => email.includes(v)) ? true : false

export { VALID_EMAIL_ENDINGS as validEnding }
```

And the section creation function :

```
import { subscribe, unsubscribe, subscribeEmail } from './subscribe.js'

const addSection = () => {
  const sectionFour = createElement('sectionFour', 'section', 'app-section app-section--image-program', 'fourth-section')
  const sectionParent = getElbyID('sectionParent', 'third-section')
  const parentSection = sectionParent.parentNode
  parentSection.insertBefore(sectionFour, sectionParent.nextSibling)

  const heading2 = createElement('heading2', 'h2', 'program-title')
  const heading2Text = document.createTextNode('Join Our Program')
  heading2.append(heading2Text)
  const parent = getElbyID('parent', 'fourth-section')

  const heading3 = createElement('heading3', 'h3', 'program-subtitle')
  const heading3Text = document.createTextNode('Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt')
  heading3.appendChild(heading3Text)
  const linebreak = createElement('linebreak', 'br')
  heading3.appendChild(linebreak)
  const textAfterBreak = document.createTextNode('ut labore et dolore magna aliqua')
  heading3.appendChild(textAfterBreak)

  const form = createElement('submitFieldWrapper', 'form', 'submitFieldWrapper', 'form')
  parent.append(heading2, heading3, form)

  const emailForm = createElement('emailForm', 'div', 'form-wrapper', 'emailForm')

  const inputForm = createElement('inputForm', 'input', 'form-input', 'submit-info')
  setAttributes(inputForm,
    'type', 'text',
    'placeholder', 'Email')
  if (localStorage.getItem('Email') !== null) {
    inputForm.setAttribute('value', localStorage.getItem('Email'))
  } else {
    inputForm.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Email')
  }

  emailForm.appendChild(inputForm)

  document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(inputForm.value)
    localStorage.setItem('Email', inputForm.value)
    subscribeEmail(inputForm.value)
  })

  const submitForm = createElement('submitForm', 'input', 'app-section__button submit-btn', 'subscribeButton')
  setAttributes(submitForm,
    'type', 'submit',
    'value', 'Subscribe')
  form.append(emailForm, submitForm)

  const isSubscribed = localStorage.getItem('isSubscribed')
  if (isSubscribed === 'true') {
    subscribe()
  } else if (isSubscribed === 'false') {
    unsubscribe()
  }
}

const createElement = (elName, htmlEl, elClass, elID) => {
  const elementName = document.createElement(htmlEl)
  elementName.className = elClass
  elementName.id = elID

  return elementName
}

const getElbyID = (elName, searchedId) => {
  const elementToSearch = document.getElementById(searchedId)

  return elementToSearch
}

const setAttributes = (elem, ...elemArguments) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < elemArguments.length; i += 2) {
    elem.setAttribute(elemArguments[i], elemArguments[i + 1])
  }
}

export const advancedSection = () => {
  addSection()
  const getHeading = document.getElementById('fourth-section')
  const sectionChildren = getHeading.children
  sectionChildren[0].innerHTML = 'Join Our Advanced Program'
  const getButton = document.getElementById('subscribeButton')
  setAttributes(getButton,
    'type', 'submit',
    'value', 'Subscribe to Advanced Program')
  getButton.className = 'app-section__button submit-btnAdvanced'
}

export default addSection
```

I dont understand where im wrong or what is missing,please help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the value is what you expect in `const isSubscribed = localStorage.getItem('isSubscribed')
  if (isSubscribed === 'true') {
    subscribe()
  } else if (isSubscribed === 'false') {
    unsubscribe()
  }
}`

Comment: Unrelated: I don't think you should do that with localStorage. What if the user deletes their browser data. Are they just no longer able to unsubscribe? You should probably add an endpoint to the API to check if a given e-mail is subscribed.

Comment: this snipped of code is for mentaining the state of the buttons after the refresh of the page,if there is a valid email in the localStorage,then the button should remain to unsubscribe state,if there are no emails,then the button should be to subscribe state

Comment: Yes,this isnt for any commercial projects,it is a task to get stronger knowledge about localStorage,thats why i should use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So,the problem was in subscribeEmail function,at e.preventDefault(),idk how it works but i changed preventDefault with the stopPropagation,and now i can subscribe and unsubscribe as much as i want.
The code now looks like this:

```
    export const subscribeEmail = (email) => {
  const isValidEmail = validateEmail(email)
  if (isValidEmail === true) {
    subscribe()
    document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      unsubscribe()
      localStorage.removeItem('Email')
      e.stopPropagation()
    })
  } else if (isValidEmail === false) {
    unsubscribe()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you click the 'Unsubscribe' button, you have not re-assigned the event handler for the 'Subscribe' event.

Add

```
  document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(inputForm.value)
    localStorage.setItem('Email', inputForm.value)
    subscribeEmail(inputForm.value)
  })
```

to the end of your `unsubcribe()` function.

Comment: I tried,it doesnt work.The most helpful thing i'd done is removing preventDefault from subscribeEmail when isValidEmail === true,and put a stopPropagation instead,it works this way

Comment: Or maybe use the `once` parameter: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener. Anyway, I'm glad you got it to work!